# JNI passing of arguments back to Java with Android 5+

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native

I am having this native code to get back an array of shorts :)

```
extern "C" 
JNIEXPORT jshortArray Java_my_application_CallerClazz_getShortArray(JNIEnv *jenv, jobject self)
{
    jshortArray shortArray = jenv->NewShortArray(size);
    jshort* p2ji = jenv->GetShortArrayElements(shortArray, JNI_FALSE);
    for(int idx = 0; idx < size; idx++)
    {
        p2ji[idx] = srcArray[idx];
    }
    return shortArray;
}
```

It works fine with all Android versions < 5. Since Android 5 the native code itself works fine, but the `short[]` on the java side is filled just with `0`.

Anybody has a tip why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the [JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) for `Get<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements()`:

> Since the returned array may be a copy of the Java array, changes made to the returned array will not necessarily be reflected in the original array until `Release<PrimitiveType>ArrayElements()` is called.

So before returning from your C++ function you should call `RelaseShortArrayElements` with `mode == 0` (`0` means *"copy back the content and free the elems buffer"*).

Comment: This was the right direction. Actually i did it with ```SetShortArrayRegion```.  But technically its the same as i read.

Comment: Wait, you're saying that you used `SetShortArrayRegion` _instead of_ `RelaseShortArrayElements`? You should always call Release after Get, because if a copy is made by Get it needs to be freed, which Release takes care of. And if no copy was made, the object probably will be pinned until you call Release, which will make it difficult for a compacting garbage collector to optimize the heap.

Comment: Well, sorry, it was ```GetShortArrayRegion```. Found some tips here http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#region_calls